# Вычисление координат внутри svg

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg

[image: исходная картинка]

Есть такой пентагон, по нему построена svg фигура вот такая

[image: svg]

Как динимически вычислять координаты и строить кружочки, строго на линиях. 
Будет присылаться массив и в зависимости от него будут, строиться кружочки.
Без каких-либо библиотек.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждая линия задаётся двумя точками, начальная и конечная.

Такая линия легко параметризуется с помощью векторной геометрии.

`A` - начальная точка, её координаты `{ax,ay}`
`B` - конечная точка, её координаты  `{bx,by}`

`B - A` - Вектор идущий от `A` к `B`.

`A + t * (B - A)` формула расчёта любой точки на отрезке `AB`.
`t` лежит на отрезке `[0,1]`.

Получаем формулу для расчёта `x` компоненты точки и `y`

```
x = ax + t * (bx - ax);
y = ay + t * (by - ay);
```

Таким образом мы можем в зависимости от `t` задавать координаты любой точки на любом отрезке.

Comment: Очень хорошее решение спасибо.

Comment: @ЭльдарГучеренко Пожалуйста, спасибо за хороший вопрос.